# How to get filter key and result tuple in Django

Tags: python, django

Assume there is a list contains all keys to search called `taglist`. To filter all Post contains tag in `taglist`, I use the following command.

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__tag__in=taglist).order_by('-id')
```

and in `class Post`

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField('PostMention')
```

in `PostMenthion`

```
class PostMention(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=200)
```

and I will get a Query list about the result.

Can I get a list of tuple like`(each_result,tag_that_used_to_found_the_result)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can `.annotate(..)` each row with the related `Tag`:

```
from django.db.models import F

Post.objects.filter(
    tags__tag__in=taglist
).annotate(
    the_tag=F('tags__tag')
).order_by('-id')
```

Here the `Post` objects will have an extra attribute `.the_tag`, that contains the string of the tag that matched. In case *multiple* tags matched, multiple `Post` objects will be in the queryset, each with their `.the_tag` attribute.

We can post-process this to a 2-tuple, but I think an attribute is a better choice, since then it is clear what this field contains.